# UITableView with NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uitableview

I’m populating a UITableView based on the values of an NSMutableArray. This table view has search results. If the user clicks in one of the results, one will navigate to another screen. If the user clicks “back”, the search results are filled in again. At this point, while the table view is being repopulated, the old values still appear, just as I want. However, since I’m doing:

```
 - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSMutableArray *m = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.searchResultsArray = m;
    [m release];
}
```

The old cells information is no longer available. Thus, the app crashes if the user clicks in one of the old cells or scrolls the UITableView because I’m accessing the mutable array which was reinitialized above.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSArray *cellArray = [searchResultsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    appDelegate.selectedCell = [searchResultsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

Do you have any suggestions concerning how should I do this properly?

Thanks.

Comment: oh, you should always use the 'self.' prefix if you have set the '@property(nonatomic.....' on a Ivariable.  e.g [searchResultsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; to be [self.searchResultsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is because you are re-initalizing the array each time the view comes back in focus, the array will then have 0 objects in, causing the issue when you select a row and reference an index in the array that simply was wiped when the viewWillAppear is called.

why not init ' self.searchResultsArray ' in viewDidLoad (remembering to undo this with release when the device receives memory warning)

let me know how you get on.

Comment: If I initialise the mutable array in viewDidLoad, both the old and new values are saved in the mutable array. Thus, both the old and new values will appear on the table view.

Comment: in which case cant you [self.searchResultsArray removeAllObjects] to clear it, then the old ones will be gone and replace with the new. im doing exactly what you are wishing to do.

Comment: I have the same problem with that solution: there is a moment where the array is empty, so if I click in one of the cells during that moment (a few milliseconds), the app crashes. I've just confirmed this by testing. In which method are you removingAllObjects from the array?

Comment: im using nsinvocation to multi-thread a method that calls a web service, im suggesting if you do the same, to not reload table view on a seperate thread, only on the main. I clear the array in the same method i pick up the new data. them slight miliseconds must be a very tiny window from emptying the array to filling back in with objects . However, that must be the same with my solution - however i havent found that small window of oppertunity to crash

Comment: I'm using NSXML to extract some XML data. I moved the removeAllObjects to the methods requestFinished and requestFailed. It's true, I didn't have the opportunity to crash it now... but I'm still not very happy with this solution because if the xml extraction takes longer than expected... it will crash! Still, thank you, it's the best I can do for now.

Comment: yeah true, but if extraction takes longer than expected, this shouldn't become an issue if you remove all objects after extraction. You could have a temporary array to store extracted data in, when this is done, copy that data to the array used in the table, reload table - J.D.

Answer (score 0):

You should reset the array only when the view loads:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSMutableArray *m = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] mutableCopy];
    self.searchResultsArray = m;
    [m release];
}
```

You should always call the `reloadData:` method when changing the data in the UITableViewDataSourceDelegate instance.

Let me know if this helps

Comment: The app doesn't crash if I reload the tableView, but the old values are gone, i.e., the tableView is blank while I'm waiting for the new results. I was looking for something like the Mail app, when you check emails. The old emails still appear and you can scroll while waiting for the new ones.

Comment: I just updated the answer. You should initialize the array only when the view loads, the you update it only when the data is ready

Comment: The array is the one that has the data. So, there are a few milliseconds where the array is empty, although the tableView is filled in with the previous search. I never used mutableCopy before, but I tried the code above and the behaviour is still the same - the application crashes because the array is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    // Your search result array with your old values
    // Now add or appened new data to your old search results.

    [self.searchResultsArray addObject:@"Your Value 1"];
    [self.searchResultsArray addObject:@"Your Value 2"];
    [self.searchResultsArray addObject:@"Your Value 3"];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

  //  if you need to add new values from a array put this code in a loop.   
}
```

It should helps you...

Thx

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are not initialising the NSArray in the right method (`viewDidLoad:`).
Using [XLData](https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLData) you don't have to care about where you set up the storage, reload the UITableView or add items to the NSArray (searchResultsArray) since it keeps track of the data (NSArray) and updates the UITableView accordingly and on the fly.